# Who's in charge? I want to fart on some authority figures to speak truth to power

Tags: achievements, south-park-the-stick-of-truth

Working on rounding out my accumulation of achievements, it seems that I may have been insufficiently diligent in my quest to fart on everyone in South Park. I say this because I've finished the game, but have not earned the **Truth to Power** achievement.

I'm not sure who I'm supposed to fart on for this achievement, because I've not earned it and I just did a loop, farting on all of the members of the PTA and school staff, Officer Barbrady, the Mayor, Wendy, Jesus, the Mountie guarding the border, Ike, the Prince of Canada, the Earl of Winnipeg, the Bishop of Banff, and the Duke of Vancouver. I even farted on Kyle and Cartman at their respective seats of power.

I am running out of people in positions of power to fart on. I've already resorted to several rather precarious leaps of logic without success.

Comment: I'm interested in this too, as I made sure to fart on literally every character in the game and still never earned this achievement.  Maybe it's bugged?

Comment: did you fart on Al Gore?

Comment: There is a typo in the title. It is supposed to say "Authorita"

Comment: +1. Gaming.SE has produced a lot of questions with hilarious names, but this is one of my favorites.

Comment: same here, first it thought it was a troll, then I thought he was talking about stack exchange achievements, which makes no sense

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The 4 people you have to fart on are:

1. Mayor of South Park.  (Located in her office)
2. Father Maxi. (Located on a bench outside of the Mayor Office)
3. Principal Victoria. (Located in the community center)
4. Minister of Montreal (Locked in a cave in Cananda. You need to fart on him before talking to him or he disappears forever).

This achievement might be glitchy. I for sure had farted on everyone, but after farting on the Minister of Montreal, I had to take another round of farting on the South Park Officials. I had the achievement unlock after using the 'cup a spell' fart on everyone.

Comment: Why Jesus was not included in this list, I'll never know.

Answer (score 6):

The correct list is:

- Mayor
- Father Maxi
- Principal Victoria
- Prime Minister of Canada

Comment: Without spoiling, make sure you do the deed with the Prime Minister before speaking with him.

Comment: Do you mean the Minister of Montreal? I don't remember ever meeting a 'Prime Minister of Canada'.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz  definitely Minister of Montreal, in the cave. Got this last night. You need to fart on him before talking to him, otherwise he disappears.

Comment: But I did fart on him. He made some dumb joke in 'Eastern Canadian' that I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've farted on the Minister of Canada in the cave, you have to use the Cup-a-Spell on the other 3.(Priest Maxi,Mayor McDaniels and Principal Victoria)